# teamcity MSBuild error, "A signing key is required in order to package this project"

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

i am using teamCity to build my .jsproj file, and at the end i getting this error.

[_CreateMainPackage] SignAppxPackage
[SignAppxPackage] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild \Microsoft\VisualStudio \v12.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1970, 9):

**error APPX0101: A signing key is required in order to package this project. Please specify a PackageCertificateKeyFile or PackageCertificateThumbprint value in the project file.**

[Step 7/7] Step build (1) (MSBuild) failed

below is the my configuration in teamCity
[image: configuration in teamCity]

It is working if i run it by cmd, can everyone help me to solve  this?

Answer (score 5):

You can disable code signing by adding: `/p:AppxPackageSigningEnabled=false` into the command line parameters section.

It is an MSBuild parameter, which will allow you to produce an unsigned package (assuming you don't require one). Note that you will not be able to publish such a package.

Comment: Please explain where to use this and why it would solve the OP's problem.  What is obvious to you may not be obvious to everybody.  Help others to understand.

Comment: The screenshot shows an older version of /p:SignAssembly=true, so that's what you would change in that case.

For more modern times, if anyone is using MSBuild, that parameter does the trick.